# ontouch and onclick on a textview not working

Tags: android

have a look at the code below...
i am setting the onclick listener on the textview and the ontouch listener but none of them is working...

what seems to be the problem>....?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog a;
    TextView text,txtNewUser ;
    ImageView image;
    View layout;
    Button ok;
    String pswrd;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context mContext = this;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_private_space);
        dialog.setTitle("Password");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_private_space,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout));
        text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        txtNewUser = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);

        image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock_symbol_android);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);

        a = builder.create();
        a.show();

        txtNewUser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("AS", "Clicked");
    return true;

            }
        });

txtNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("AS", "Clicked");
    }
});
    }
```

here is the code of textview from the xml of the dialog layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout" >

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tvNewUser"
    android:text="New User?"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:clickable="true"

    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Enter password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="100"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >


    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOK"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="OK" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add in your complete xml ?

Comment: have you used custom dialog ? if no then txtNewUser = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);
remove dialog from the above line.

Comment: Is this textview a part of some dialog?

Comment: i am using a custom dialog and that textview tvNewUser is on that dialog

Comment: Use this line  txtNewUser = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser); and let me know what happen.. remove  txtNewUser = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);
this line..

Comment: hello can you please attach layout of Dialog also

Comment: added the full layout xml file also @sarvan kumar

Comment: @kashifmehmood - Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: hello i am asking dialog layout  : R.layout.custom_dialog_private_space

Comment: @user370305 it gives a null pointer exception now....

Comment: @sravankumar the xml code is the code of the custom_dialog_private_space......

Comment: @kashifmehmood - If you are able to view image in your dialog then it should work.. Just check whether its for TextView its null or not. Your solution is only that line..

Comment: @user370305 its not giving exception onclick or ontouch but as this activity is called .... it gives a null pointer exception

Comment: Did you check why its give you NPE?

Comment: i think the problem is that the textview is set to be a view on a dialog and when it tries to find textview like findviewbyid then it gives NPE...(thats what i think)

Comment: hi i posted one more answer , now you can view that answer , if u want full code send me ur id i will send code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of infalter use window class
2. return false in on Touch listener
3. set contenet view to your main activity

   ```
   package com.collabera.labs.sai;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class HomePage extends Activity {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder;
       AlertDialog a;
       TextView text, txtNewUser;
       ImageView image;
       Button ok;
       String pswrd;

       public Window mWindow;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_private_space);
           ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
           final Context mContext = this;
           Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomePage.this);

           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_private_space);
           dialog.setTitle("Password");
           dialog.setCancelable(true);
           dialog.show();
           mWindow = dialog.getWindow();
           Log.w(" dialog is " + mWindow.toString(), "-------");
           text = (TextView) mWindow.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
           txtNewUser = (TextView) mWindow.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);
           image = (ImageView) mWindow.findViewById(R.id.image);
           image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

           txtNewUser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

               @Override
               public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                               .show();
                   Log.v("AS", "Touched");
                   return false;

               }
           });

           txtNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.v("AS", "Clicked");
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: neither is the image showing nor the ok button and plus the foreground of the dialog is the same as the background because of the setContentView is same

Comment: so u can set content view how u want just add another xml file .

Comment: use android:height="wrap_content"  instaed of fill parent

Comment: what was the problem anyways with the Inflator... or something else...?

Answer (score 1):

I think.. you should also return

```
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

from onTouch function.. **instead of true** because true means the event is consumed by touch and other actions are not called for this event.. in this case **onClick**

Comment: the method onTouchEvent is undefined for the type object

Answer (score 0):

In toast both cases you have written clicked so change to touch in onTouch listener and return false  at onTouch Listener:

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {
    private TextView txtNewUser;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        txtNewUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);

        txtNewUser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Touched ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                Log.v("AS", "Touched");
                return false;

            }
        });

        txtNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("AS", "Clicked");
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: its just a message and doesnot matters but none of the toasts are executed

Comment: hello now try this code , just now i tried , if u want i will send my code also .

Comment: its not a simple textview . the textview is located on a custom dialog that i am creating... c this...
txtNewUser = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvNewUser);

Comment: can u please send total project ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the way i used to make imageview clickable:

```
public class Main extends Activity **implements OnClickListener** {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


   ImageView  profile_btn=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.x_Btn);
   x_btn.setOnClickListener(this) ;


    ImageView  food_btn=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.y_Btn);

    ybtn.setOnClickListener(this); 
   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.x_Btn:
            //do some thing;break;
                  case R.id.y_Btn:
    //do some thing;break;
                  }
     }
}
```

Comment: i am not using imageview...i am using textview present on a dialog